# Hide all elements before loading chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So, I am trying to do something like parental control. When I start my extension for the first time it works fine, but when I use it again elements don't hide, whole page loads and then it redirects, I want to hide all elements on page and then redirect, I am not using onBeforeRequest I want to use it with google search too and I don't know if I can put regex inside urls option. My manifest is ok, I start content script at "document_start".

background.js

```
var activeTabUrl;
var regex = /http:\/\/www.youporn.com\//

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
}, function (arrayOfTabs) {

    activeTabUrl = arrayOfTabs[0].url;
});

if (activeTabUrl.match(regex)) {

    chrome.tabs.update({
        url: "http://google.com/"
    })
} else {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
        action: "show_my_page"
    }, function (response) {});
}
});
```

myscript.js (content_script)

```
   _ini();

function _ini() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.display = "none";

    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (msg.action == 'show_my_page') {
            document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you try inserting a `<style>* {display: none !important;}</style>` by script?

Comment: yes, it doesn't work. weirdest thing is that when i have opened inspector in chrome it works every time.

Comment: maybe at the time the content script script executed, the document is not ready yet. Try to replace _init() to document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _init); and see whether it works.

Comment: no it doesn't, whole page shows and then redirect i want to hide everything until page is redirected. I think there can be problem with message which is sent to content script but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry  xwhyLikeThis ,it kinda works, function is _ini not _init. Page flashes for a sacond and then it redirects. Thanks it helped a bit but i would like to do it properly.

Comment: Sometimes content script may execute at document-start before `html` exists. Check the console after enabling "[x] Preserve log" in devtools (F12). If this is the case you'll have to either use setInterval to check periodically or MutationObserver. Another remote possibility is that initially the tab contains a dummy `<html></html>` which is discarded upon the first DOM operation. BTW redirection may be implemented better via `webRequest` API.

Answer (score 0):

That's a wrong approach, but first why it fails.

If you're executing at `document_start`, then the only node existing in the dom would be the `document` node. Not even `html` yet.

Yes, you could potentially wait for `html` node to appear, but this is very roundabout. Your goal is to prevent navigation in the first place - and for blocker-style functionality there's the [`webrequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) (which, IIRC, was specifically implemented for AdBlock).

Here's a minimal sample from the docs themselves:

```
  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) { return {cancel: true}; },
    {urls: ["*://www.evil.com/*"]},
    ["blocking"]);
```

You can also redirect that with a `redirectUrl` instead of `cancel` in the blocking response. See also [CatBlock](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/extensions/catblock.zip) for a complete sample.

Comment: I want to check words from file. I don't know if there is possibility to reach this with "urls".

Comment: That's how AdBlock works on Chrome. You could look at [ABP's source](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockpluschrome).